# are nested sets possible in Android sqlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, nested-sets

Well i have a question I'm making a project with albums and files. Its using a file tree structure and is synced with an website run on Laravel. The website uses nested sets for the data structure.

Is it possible to use nested sets in android and SQLite? 
if this is possible, how?

if not does somebody know a different solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested sets are not among the [data types directly supported by SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#storageclasses).

It might be possible to use a normalized database schema to store the sets and their values, but querying them would require recursive [CTEs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) which are not supported in most versions of SQLite shipped with Android.

Answer (score 1):

Nested sets is an encoding technique for modelling hierarchies in a relational database. It has nothing to do with database support of special types or SQL extension for recursion. It's application level thing and it works in any relational database, just like any other indexed integer column. SQLite is no exception here.

[Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) is a good overview. Specifically for SQL queries, I wrote a Python library called *Fangorn* for nestsed sets trees that supports MySQL and SQLite. It shouldn't be hard to extract the queries for certain operations from [this module](https://bitbucket.org/saaj/fangorn/src/default/fangorn/ns.py), and use it in Java DAO.